# Confirm boxes not working for delete links only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ujs

I am currently banging my head against the desk trying to figure out why this is not working. I am trying to get the ujs confirmation box to show up when a delete link is clicked.  Currently, the item is deleted with no confirmation box.  Here is my delete link:

```
<%= link_to "void", project, method: :delete, data: {comfirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this project?"} %>
```

Here is where it gets strange. The following link (not a delete link) works as expected:

```
<%= link_to "About", about_path, data: {confirm: "test test"} %>
```

I did some digging in the gem itself and was able to discover that, with the delete link, the data-message attribute is not being parsed correctly in the following code.  Specifically, the

```
if (!message) { return true; }
```

is returning true, where message is defined as follows:

```
message = element.data('confirm')
```

Note: element is the entire link itself.  Can anyone help me find out why this is happening? I am using Rails 3.2 if it helps.

Comment: You've written "comfirm" instead of "confirm"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this, just make it confirm instead of comfirm, and it works fine.

```
<%= link_to "void", project,method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this project?"} %>
```

Comment: I CAN'T BELIEVE I didn't catch that.  I think I need to take a break before I do some real damage.  Thanks Sarwan.